# Using Spark Pivot for get_dummies Substitute

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The following code sets up the dataframe in a perfect format but I need to have it also name the columns "correctly."

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "X", "a"),
    (1, "Z", "b"),
    (2, "X", "b"),
    (3, "X", "c"),
    (4, "Y", "c"),
    (5, "Y", "a")
], ["id","category", "other_thing"])

pivotDF = df.groupBy("id").pivot("category").count()

pivotDF.show()

+---+----+----+----+
| id|   X|   Y|   Z|
+---+----+----+----+
|  0|   1|null|null|
|  5|null|   1|null|
|  1|null|null|   1|
|  3|   1|null|null|
|  2|   1|null|null|
|  4|null|   1|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

I would need this as the output:

```
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id|   category_X|   category_Y|   category_Z|
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  0|   1         |         null|         null|
|  5|null         |            1|         null|
|  1|null         |         null|            1|
|  3|   1         |         null|         null|
|  2|   1         |         null|         null|
|  4|null         |            1|         null|
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I add the column names programmatically (i.e., I don't have to manually type in "category" in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can rename:

```
>>> pivot_col = "category"
>>> pivotDF = df.groupBy("id").pivot(pivot_col).count()
>>> new_names = pivotDF.columns[:1] + \
...   ["{0}_{1}".format(pivot_col, c) for c in pivotDF.columns[1:]]
>>>  pivotDF.toDF(*new_names)
```

Comment: Thx @LostInOverflow. Your code works (though you need to add a ")" to the last line. 

That said I'm going to edit my question because I need to be able to add the "category" portion programmatically.